# How to zoom and pan a gameobject not the whole scene in unity

Tags: zooming, unity-game-engine, pinchzoom, pan, pinch

I have several images in my scene, I managed to make the zoom and pan work but the problem is, All of the images are zooming in at the same time. The scripts are place on each gameobject. I used gameobject for the images.

Answer (score 0):

You need apply a filter so you just appli the transformations to one game object, since every one of them are GameObjects I recommend use [raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) to sellect an object and then activate his Zoom.cs script just for this object.

I sugest to use just one Zoom.cs in the scene instead of every object having his own copy, then change your function to work with one game object as a paremeter and, when you touch your game object then that object will be the one to suffer the transformation.

If you doesn't want to implement a raycast or change your function at all, then you could set all the images inside a matrix, or use an index system, the central image, or the index you designed, will be the one to suffer the transformations. so you can scroll betwen your gaery and be sure that just the image that you designate in your matrix/index will be the choosen one. The trouble here is that you need to fully control the scroll animation so no one of the images will be in a wrong place like in between two index.